# How to refer to figure I clicked to change its properties and move it?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouse

I have a figure in `Canvas` in WPF application. This figure is generated by program (I click a button and then a figure appears). How to order the `Figure_MouseLeftButtonDown` function to change some properties of THIS figure? Also I want to move this figure by dragging. Now I have something like this:

```
var ell = new Ellipse() { 
    Name = "FirstEllipse", 
    Width = 150, 
    Height = 100, 
    Margin = new Thickness(200, 150, 0, 0), 
    Fill = Brushes.Red 
}; 
ell.MouseLeftButtonDown += Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown; 
canvas.Children.Add(ell); 

private void Figure_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{ 
    sender.SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, Brushes.Aquamarine);
}
```

Comment: "Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown" not like "Figure_MouseLeftButtonDown"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it, maybe this answer will help somebody else. Ellipse ellip = new Ellipse();
            ellip = (Ellipse)sender;
            ellip.SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, Brushes.Aquamarine);

Comment: Or shorter `((Ellipse)sender).Fill = Brushes.Aquamarine;`